# MVC Survey and capturing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im kinda new to MVC and have built a site with a risk calculator.
This all works fine the site works for users logging in and the form calculates the form then sends the user to the correct page.

When a user signs in with account and fills out the survey i want to capture the score on the database but cannot work out how/where to do this. Should i be writing the code in the behind file for the survey form?

here is the script

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function test_it(entry) {
                if (entry.value != null && entry.value.length != 0) {
                    entry.value = "" + eval(entry.value);
                }
                computeForm(entry.form);
            }
            function computeForm(form) {
                var total = 0

                for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                    if (form.a[count].checked) {
                        var total = total + parseInt(form.a[count].value);
                    }
                }

                for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                    if (form.b[count].checked) {
                        var total = total + parseInt(form.b[count].value);
                    }
                }

                for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                    if (form.c[count].checked) {
                        var total = total + parseInt(form.c[count].value);
                    }
                }

                for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                    if (form.d[count].checked) {
                        var total = total + parseInt(form.d[count].value);
                    }
                }

                for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                    if (form.e[count].checked) {
                        var total = total + parseInt(form.e[count].value);
                    }
                }

                for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                    if (form.f[count].checked) {
                        var total = total + parseInt(form.f[count].value);
                    }
                }

                for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                    if (form.g[count].checked) {
                        var total = total + parseInt(form.g[count].value);
                    }
                }

                for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                    if (form.h[count].checked) {
                        var total = total + parseInt(form.h[count].value);
                    }
                }

                for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                    if (form.i[count].checked) {
                        var total = total + parseInt(form.i[count].value);
                    }
                }

                for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                    if (form.j[count].checked) {
                        var total = total + parseInt(form.j[count].value);
                    }
                }

                for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                    if (form.k[count].checked) {
                        var total = total + parseInt(form.k[count].value);
                    }
                }

                for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
                    if (form.l[count].checked) {
                        var total = total + parseInt(form.l[count].value);
                    }
                }
                if (total <= 5) { window.location = "End_Page_1" }
                else if (total <= 12) { window.location = "End_Page_2" }
                else if (total <= 24) { window.location = "End_Page_3" }
                else if (total <= 30) { window.location = "End_Page_4" }
                else if (total <= 48) { window.location = "End_Page_5" }
            }

        </script>
```

Any ideas how i could do this would be much appreciated.
Andy

Comment: So you have a form with input fields? which takes some values and you need to process them? and redirect to different page depending on the output?

Comment: hi @Reddy thanks for your reply. I have a survey form that counts a score and depending on that score sends the user to a profile. Which is working fine. I want to record this information using my survey model and database, so that a returning user can see previous surveys in a basic table format.I have the model created and intend to create a controller section for each of these individual form items and the final score. My issue comes when trying to write this controller nothing appears to work correctly.

Comment: How are you doing all the counting of score?? only in javascript?

Comment: Hi @Reddy, Sorry for late response. Yes doing the counting in the above script and at the end  it sends user off to a page depending on the score. Since i am using MVC I need to incorporate this into a controller action to collect the data or something similar. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Reddy,

Thanks for your response, sorry again for delay.
I will test this out now that i have access to the internet :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a Model

```
public class Calculator
{
public string Field1 {get;set;}
public string Field2 {get;set;}
public string Field3 {get;set;}
...
}
```

write a controller which would just send a empty model to the view. Like

```
public ActionResult FillSurvey()
{
  Calculator calci =  new Calculator();
  return View(calci);
}
```

now right click this action and choose `add view` here choose strongly typed view. Choose your Model `Calculator` and also choose scffold template. choose create. A new View will be generated where in you can enter values and write one more method/Action in controller.Like

```
    [HTTPPOST]
     public ActionResult FillSurvey(Calculator calci)
        {
    //do whatever you want here. You will have all the values entered in UI 
//captured in this method
        }
```